# when executing the program, it gives an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

```
import requests

from datetime import datetime

def get_from_binance():

    req = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT")
    response = req.json()
    sell_price = response["price"]
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}\nBTC Binance: {sell_price}")


def get_from_bittrex():

    req2 = requests.get("https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=USD-BTC")
    response2 = req2.json()
    sell_price2 = response2["result"]['Last']
    print(f"BTC Bittrex: {sell_price2}")


def get_from_bitfinex():

    req3 = requests.get("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD")
    response3 = req3.json()
    sell_price3 = response3["0"]["1"]
    print(f"BTC bitfinex: {sell_price3}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    get_from_binance()
    get_from_bittrex()
    get_from_bitfinex()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Firstly, this is not a question, secondly, we're not here to do your debugging for you. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including minimal but complete code, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit].

Comment: Can you be more specifc which part of the code fails? I can only guess that any of these jsons are lists not dicts, but I don't know which one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_from_bitfinex():

    req3 = requests.get("https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=tBTCUSD")
    response3 = req3.json()
    sell_price3 = response3[0][1] # <-- these should be integers instead of strings
    print(f"BTC bitfinex: {sell_price3}")
```